# Required NSDate in PST

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

I want current date and time in PST. I used this code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"]];

NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"String:%@",timeStamp);
```

It returns correct date and time in PST in string form but I want NSDate in PST. So when I change NSString to NSDate like this:

```
NSDate *currentPST = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeStamp];
NSLog(@"currentPST Date:%@",currentPST);
```

It returns date in GMT. I have done R&D but all in vain.Output is:

```
String:2011-05-18 22:28:54 PDT
currentPST Date:2011-05-19 05:28:54 +0000
```

Can anyone suggest a solution please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Cocoa, `NSDate` is an abstract representation of a date with no time zone information applied.

Whenever you print a `NSDate` object, it will print the date value corresponds to the default timezone(your device timezone).  Your device timezone is GMT thats why you get the value like that. If you look into that deeply, both the time where same, but the timezone varies.